# About Android Development IDEs and Frameworks

Tags: java, android, performance, frameworks, ide

I am started to get into Android Development. I have an experience with PHP and .NET, however, am new to Java. Got to know a lot of things about Java in the past few days.

Wanted to know

- What could be the best IDE for Android Development?
- Shall i use core Java for developing Apps or should i consider any frameworks like PhoneGap or Roboguice or any other?

I have tried using Eclipse (the most voted one) and Jetbrains Idea 12.1.3 (second most popular, as per Internet forums).

I have found both IDEs great, however, Jetbrains slows down the Windows (I am on Windows 7) performance :-(

Anyways, any suggestions for a newbie like me to buckle up and learn a new programming language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eclipse is the most popular, but you can use the new Android Studio which is based on the jetbrains IDE (IntelliJ IDEA). 
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Also, you can use Netbeans with the Kenai Plugin. There are many tutorials on the internet for installing that plugin
https://kenai.com/projects/nbandroi

In my opinion, if you want to develop right now, you shall use eclipse. Android studio is in a beta phase and netbeans plugin is useless than eclipse (from my point of view)

Comment: Would you recommend me to use core Java or shall i start with some Android Frameworks?

Comment: I recommend you to start learning a little bit of Java. When you were familiar with the language, start with android.

Comment: In the other hand, I don't recommend frameworks for one only application. Phonegap is valid to make multi-platform apps, but remember that a native app is always better than a app made with some framework (data access, cpu,..) 
For example, facebook changed its application from HTML5 to native in iOS

Comment: Thanks for the information! I will start with Java for my android app!

Answer (score 2):

Google released a new IDE, Android Studio, for android at [Google I/O 2013](https://developers.google.com/events/io/), might be worth looking at (I haven't tried it myself yet): http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

It comes with this caution, however:

> Caution: Android Studio is currently available as an early access preview. Several features are either incomplete or not yet implemented and you may encounter bugs.

I cannot comment on the use of frameworks (I do not have enough experience with them).

Since you have experience with .NET, Java shouldn't be too hard to learn, as it's very similar to C#.